# Determining data types using ADO.NET in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

In the past I have used the code below to find out what datatypes the columns of a table. Now that I am using ADO.NET, I cannot a find a way of doing that with VB.NET and ADO.NET.  How would I do it using ADO.NET?  Do I have to enumerate all the data types or is there a "isnumeric" or a "isstring" type function?

```
Select Case rs(sColumnName).Type
    Case ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedSmallInt, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedTinyInt, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedBigInt, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedInt, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSingle, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSmallInt, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBigInt, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDecimal, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDouble, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adNumeric, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency '
        sType="NUMERIC"
    Case ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarWChar, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adWChar, ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar ' ADD ALL THE STRING TYPES
        sType="STRING"                                
End Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetDataTypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatatypename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `SqlDataReader` class.

Example:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Database=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.CommandText = "select * from table1"
cmd.Connection = con
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

MessageBox.Show(reader.GetDataTypeName(1))
```